# is there a function like getdelim is c++?

Tags: c++, c, file-io

Is there a function in c++ that works like the `getdelim` function in C? I want to process a file using `std::ifstream` object, so I cannot use `getdelim` here.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), both the free function for `std::string` and the member for char buffers have an overload taking a delimiter (BTW `getdelim` is a GNU extension)

Comment: getdelim is not exactly a GNU extension: I just found it as an Open Group Specification at http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html

Comment: thanks for that info..ya i know that getdelim is not a standard C function, but it works on FILE* only.

Comment: One more question... how do I check for end-of-file using the getline function? Coz, using .eof() is not recommended as it wont signal eof until I attempt to read beyond eof.

Comment: @mkluwe, I've been induced into error by the manpage on my system which says that getline and getdelim are GNU extensions.  I've not looked if there are differences with the OpenGroup spec.

Comment: Never mind, but sometimes "is a xyz extension" has a bad connotation, and I just wanted to take that out. I know the man page, seems to be outdated…

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Boost then I recommend the [Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) library. The following example tokenizes a stream using whitespace and semicolons as separators:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

int main() {

   typedef boost::char_separator<char> Sep;
   typedef boost::tokenizer<Sep> Tokenizer;

   std::string str("This :is: \n a:: test");
   Tokenizer tok(str, Sep(": \n\r\t"));
   std::copy(tok.begin(), tok.end(), 
             std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Output:

```
This
is
a
test
```

If you want to tokenize the contents of an input stream it can be done easily:

```
 int main() {

     std::ifstream ifs("myfile.txt");
     typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> StreamIter;
     StreamIter file_iter(ifs);

     typedef boost::char_separator<char> Sep;
     typedef boost::tokenizer<Sep, StreamIter> Tokenizer;

     Tokenizer tok(file_iter, StreamIter(),  Sep(": \n\r\t"));

     std::copy(tok.begin(), tok.end(), 
             std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
 }
```